Has anyone had trouble with SPSS syntax not correctly reading instructions to create a scatterplot?
I often use Hayes' moderation macro, which generates syntax for plotting the moderation. The syntax can be copied and pasted into a new syntax window. It's always worked beautifully. Until this week. This past week, rather than creating a plot with three lines (one SD above, below, and at mean), the resulting graph showed about 20 lines.
I sent the syntax to a colleague, who successfully used it on his SPSS (same version as mine); in other words, the syntax generated the expected moderation plot; it did what it was supposed to do. So the problem is not with the syntax; it's with how SPSS is reading the syntax on my computer. I deleted SPSS from my computer and re-installed it with the most recent version. The problem persists. Has anyone had this problem, and can you suggest any fixes?
